# Intent - Put and Get Extras - Android - NullPointer

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I have nullpointer exception.

Function in MainActivity.

```
public void intentLoginUser(){
    Intent aux = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginUserSplashScreen.class);

    aux.putExtra("user", username);
    aux.putStringArrayListExtra("notificationList", MainActivity.this.notificationsList);
    aux.putStringArrayListExtra("friendList", MainActivity.this.friendList);
    aux.putStringArrayListExtra("localizationList", MainActivity.this.localizationList);

    MainActivity.this.startActivity(aux);
}
```

Function in another Activity, named LoginUserSplashScreen

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar
    notificationList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("notificationList");
    friendList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("friendList");
    localizationList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("localizationList");
    myUsername = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user");
    Log.e("Erro Aqui YA?", myUsername.get(0));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginuser);}
```

What's wrong?
I have nullpointer in function `onCreate`, in `Log.e();` ... I'm trying debugging that, but I can't.

EDIT - Nullpointer in function `onCreate` in line `Log.e()`
Because all lists are null (can't get anything from last activity).

Comment: which line exactly does nullpointer exception happen?

Comment: Nullpointer in function onCreate in line Log.e()... 
Because all lists are null... 'cause cant get anything from last activity - i'll edit my post.

Comment: Since you didn't set the logcat is kind of hard to tell, but I see an error in getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user");, because "user" in the intent extra is not specified as a List...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution,

In MainActivity:

```
public      ArrayList<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<String>();
public      Queue<String> serverMessages = new LinkedList<String>();
public      ArrayList<String> notificationsList = new ArrayList<String>();
public      ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();     
public      ArrayList<String> localizationList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void intentLoginUser(){
    Intent aux = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginUserSplashScreen.class);
    usernameList.add(username);
    aux.putStringArrayListExtra("user", MainActivity.this.usernameList);
    aux.putStringArrayListExtra("notificationList", MainActivity.this.notificationsList);
    aux.putStringArrayListExtra("friendList", MainActivity.this.friendList);
    aux.putStringArrayListExtra("localizationList", MainActivity.this.localizationList);

    MainActivity.this.startActivity(aux);
}
```

In LoginUserSplashScreen

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar
    notificationList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("notificationList");
    friendList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("friendList");
    localizationList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("localizationList");
    myUsername = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user");
    Log.e("Erro Aqui YA?", myUsername.get(0));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginuser);

    // Start timer and launch main activity
   IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
    launcher.start();
}
```

And Log.e(); works and pass all data.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
```

instead of

```
getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user");
```

"user" was not ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mismatch in your put and get calls.

```
aux.putExtra("user", username);

myUsername = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user");
```

Use `aux.putStringArrayListExtra("user", username)` with `getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user")` (assuming username is an ArrayList< String >) and use `aux.putExtra("user", username)` with `getIntent().getStringExtra("user")` (assuming username is a String).

Answer (score 1):

In main activity you have assigned object with putExtra

```
aux.putExtra("user", username);
```

But in receiving point your getStringArrayListExtra

```
myUsername = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user");
Log.e("Erro Aqui YA?", myUsername.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is error code

```
aux.putExtra("user", username);
myUsername = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user");
```

you can use bundle,this code is work for you

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
```

or

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("user", username);
aux.putExtras(bundle);

getIntent().getExtras().getString("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that when you assign myUsername, you are saying that the variable with key "user" is a StringArrayList, but instead it is a String when you put it in the intent. The putExtra() method takes String types, not StringArrayLists.